# Show local ip inside .sh script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

We want to show local server ip inside .sh script, any ideas how this could be done ?

Comment: That's not an example. If you want an answer without even bothering to try then why not buy some consultancy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
localiphere=$(hostname -i)
```

But the exact command to be used inside the parenthesis depends on how many IPs you have on a server and which distribution you are using.

Basically, you need to put the command which will return the server IP, but that command will vary from system to system. On Debian `hostname -i` will return the main server IP.

If you are looking for server public IP and not private IPs, even if you have multiple public IPs on your server, you can use online services like [ifconfig.co](https://ifconfig.co/) and similar to get main public IP of the server regardless of the system you are running.

```
localiphere=$(curl ifconfig.co)
```

Comment: With RHEL7: `hostname -I`

Comment: In my Debian `hostname -i` returns `127.0.0.1` while `hostname -I` returns `192.168.1.120`

Comment: -I should return all IP addresses, from manpage, [-I|--all-ip-addresses], it returns all IPs on all Debians I tried it.